# route is not hitting nested controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this structure in my app using Express and Node.js

```
//index.js
const authRoutes = require('./auth);
app.use('/auth', authRoutes(logger));


 //auth.js
  const authController = require('./authController);
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();

  module.exports = function(logger) 
  {
    return function(req,res,next){
       router.post('/signup',authController.signup(logger));
        return router 
  }
  //authController.js

const signup =  (logger) => 
   {
     logger.info('outside');
        return function(req,res,next)
        {
          logger.info('inside');
        }
}
module.exports = {
   signup
}
```

The code prints outside but not inside what's the problem?
and if the variable passed by app.use is the problem is it efficient if i required the logger module when I need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be like this

```
//auth.js
const authController = require('./authController);
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(logger) 
{
     router.post('/signup',authController.signup(logger));
      return router 
}
```